# WinDivert throws Exception: {code=3, message='null'}

Tags: java, windows

Try WinDivert (jdivert) on Windows 10.

Every time packet match program throws exception. For example, filter all icmp:

```
        WinDivert w = new WinDivert("icmp");
        
        try {
            w.open();
            int i = 0;
            while (i<10) {
                Packet packet = w.recv();
                System.out.println(packet);
                w.send(packet);
                i++;
            }
            w.close();
        } catch (WinDivertException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

First packet match printed:

```
Packet {IPv4 {version=4, srcAddr=127.0.0.1, dstAddr=127.0.0.1, IHL=5, DSCP=0, ECN=0, length=60, ID=b7d3 RESERVED=false, DF=false, MF=false, fragOff=0 TTL=128 proto=ICMP, cksum=84eb}, ICMPv4 {type=8, code=0, cksum=4d4a, restOfHdr=00010011}, direction=OUTBOUND, iface=[0, 0], raw=4500003CB7D30000800184EB7F0000017F00000108004D4A000100116162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F7071727374757677616263646566676869}
```

And on w.send(packet) get an exception:

```
WinDivertException{code=3, message='null'}
        at com.github.ffalcinelli.jdivert.exceptions.WinDivertException.throwExceptionOnGetLastError(WinDivertException.java:57)
        at com.github.ffalcinelli.jdivert.Packet.recalculateChecksum(Packet.java:359)
        at com.github.ffalcinelli.jdivert.WinDivert.send(WinDivert.java:271)
        at com.github.ffalcinelli.jdivert.WinDivert.send(WinDivert.java:234)
```

Always.
Run as admin.

If using w.send(packet), I receive exception.

Try:
`WinDivert w = new WinDivert("icmp", Layer.NETWORK, 0, Flag.NO_CHECKSUM);`

No changes.

Why error occures on recalculateChecksum every time?

PS: I try change filter, for example, from `'icmp'` to `'inbound && icmp && ip.SrcAddr == 192.168.2.30'`. No changes.

I try run this example with python and everything works! So I don't think it is a windpws problem. May be problem with libs or java version or somethink like this?